# In a one to many relationship should I include a default for all rows or just check for nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :office
end
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

There is a default Office that all employees are in and some will be in a different office. Is it better to make the foreign_key null for everyone and just contain a value for the special people or create an office and make that the default for everyone except the special people?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to change your relations to the following:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
  validates :office_id, presence: true # this forces the Employee objects to have a value for `office_id`
end

class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end
```

With this configuration, you could make requests like this:

```
montreal_employees = Office.where(location: 'Montreal').employees
```

---

To make a default value, you could add a class method on the Office model in order to use the default office if none is set for a new Employee:

```
# Office model
def self.default
  self.where(internal_reference: :default).first # this line implies that you have a column internal_reference
  # and that there is a record having it set to 'default'
end

# Employee model
before_create :set_office_to_default, if: ->{ self.office_id.blank? }

def set_office_to_default
  self.office = Office.default
end
```